# Family trapped underground/another dimension and forced to play a game show

Tags: science-fiction, identify-this-movie

OK, I'm looking for this movie for a long time now but I don't remember much of it, I've seen it when I was a kid and it's stuck in my brain ever since. Now, here is what I remember:

A family (I know they were husband and wife, but I'm not sure if they had kids) is transported underground or some kind of other dimension where they were forced to compete in some kind of TV show. I remember that they were sitting in chairs that got higher every time they did something correct and eventually they've gone high enough to get back on surface.

I know it's not much, but that's everything I remember.

Comment: I once hallucinated something like this when I was high lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are thinking of [Stay Tuned](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105466/), with John Ritter and Paw Dawber, which came out in 1992.

According to IMDB,

> A husband and wife are sucked into a hellish TV and have to survive a gauntlet of twisted versions of TV shows they find themselves in.

I think I saw it in the theater. I don't remember if it had the game show theme throughout, but they certainly had to live a lot of TV experiences before returning home.

Comment: For having one relatively well known star and a really well known one, I think it was kind of a flop.

Comment: It wasn't a gameshow through out the whole thing, just the first or second segment. They go into the old west, a cartoon, medieval France, and even a Salt N Pepa video. God I loved this movie.

Comment: I can not find words to thank you enough, i've been looking for this movie for a loooong time.. I can finaly see it again.. Million thanks!!